# Unable to connect SQL Server db in Windows platform from open shift container platform

Tags: sql-server, containers, openshift, redhat-containers

We hosted a .Net core 2.2 API in Red Hat Open shift container platform. API is using Entity Framework connecting to a SQL Server db on Windows Server, but both the container platform, SQL Server are on the same domain. 
Now the API is unable to establish connection with the SQL server db. We tried with SQL Auth, but still the API hosted on container pod is trying to establish sql connection using kerberos, which has following issue.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot authenticate using Kerberos. Ensure Kerberos has been initialized on the client with 'kinit' and a Service Principal Name has been registered for the SQL Server to allow Kerberos authentication.

Need some inputs on What are the additional setup, configurations required to connect SQL Server from open shift container platform ? 
Right now there are no environment variables, config maps, additional drivers for SQL configured in the open shift container platform.

Comment: Did you set up networking? A container can't connect to the host or other containers until you do

Comment: Networking ? - I am not sure. But what I know is, both linux platform, SQL Server are on the same domain/network according to my organization.

Comment: Hey, Did you get its solution? I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with mine was the connection string. I had to remove **"Trusted_Connection=true"**